# PIC programming which bits are which in TRIS register

Tags: pic, pic18

I am trying to understand PIC18 code in a format like `TRISB &= 0b11100000`.
What is the order the individual RB pins appear in? i.e. is this register setting RB0-RB2 as input, or RB5-RB7 as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the code `TRISB &= 0b11100000`, the binary value sets the direction of the lowest pins, RB0-RB2, as outputs, and the highest, RB5-RB7, as inputs.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't touch RB5-RB7, it leaves them as they are. Because it's a `&=`, not a `=` operation.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't change the states of ` RB5-RB7`; it only clears bits RB0 to RB4 to make them outputs while leaving `RB5-RB7` in their current states.

Answer (score 1):

After using `TRISB &= 0b11100000`, RB5-RB7 will keep their state and RB0-RB4 will be cleared - set to outputs.

Usually clearing bits is done with `TRISB &= ~(0b00011111)` for 'clarity'